# SQL Server row to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a SQL Table with the following structure:

```
Engine_No Date  Process Bolt_No1 B1Value1 B1Value2 B1Value3 Bolt_No2 B2Value1 B2Value2 B2Value3  Bolt_No3 B3Value1 B3Value2 B3Value3 Bolt_No4 B4Value1 B4Value2 B4Value3
```

I want to display the following results of a query:

```
SR NO  Engine_No Date  Process B1Bolt_No1 B1Value1 B1Value2 B1Value3          
SR NO  Engine_No Date  Process B2Bolt_No2 B2Value1 B2Value2 B2Value3   
SR NO  Engine_No Date  Process B3Bolt_No3 B3Value1 B3Value2 B3Value3  
SR NO  Engine_No Date  Process B4Bolt_No4 B4Value1 B4Value2 B4Value3
```

Can someone suggest a Query that achieves this?

Comment: Columns in SQL tables are unique.  Your data structure does not make sense.

Comment: You may be able to use either PIVOT or a case statement to output in the format you want. However the example table provided has duplicate field names Value1, Value2 and Value3 are all used 4 times each. Provide details of your table and what query you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values are actually stored in valid column names, then the simplest way is to use `union all`.  However, a more performing way is unpivot or `cross apply`:

```
select t.Engine_No, t.Date, t.Process, b.Bolt_No, b.Value1, b.Value2, b.Value3 
from t cross apply
     (values (Bolt_No1, Value1_1 Value1_2 Value1_3),
             (Bolt_No2, Value2_1 Value2_2 Value2_3),
             (Bolt_No3, Value3_1 Value3_2 Value3_3),
             (Bolt_No4, Value4_1 Value4_2 Value4_3)
     ) b(Bolt_No, Value1 Value2 Value3);
```

I have no idea what `SR NO` is.  It is not mentioned in the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your column names to something like this

```
Engine_No Date  Process Bolt_No1 B1Value1 B1Value2 B1Value3 
                        Bolt_No2 B2Value1 B2Value2 B2Value3  
                        Bolt_No3 B3Value1 B3Value2 B3Value3 
                        Bolt_No4 B4Value1 B4Value2 B4Value3
```

You might query it like this:

```
          SELECT Engine_No,Date,Process,Bolt_No1 AS BoltNo,B1Value1 AS Value1,B1Value2 AS Value2,B1Value3 AS Value3 FROM YourTable
UNION ALL SELECT Engine_No,Date,Process,Bolt_No2,B2Value1,B2Value2,B2Value3 FROM YourTable
UNION ALL SELECT ...
```

Comment: i want row to column data

Comment: @AmolBotikar, did you try this? What else do you expect to get?