# SQL Server Row To Columns Data

Tags: sql-server

I have data in a SQL Server table with the following structure:

```
Engine_No Date  Process Bolt_No1 B1Value1 B1Value2 B1Value3 Bolt_No2 B2Value1 B2Value2 B2Value3  Bolt_No3 B3Value1 B3Value2 B3Value3 Bolt_No4 B4Value1 B4Value2 B4Value3
```

I want to display the following results of a query:

```
Engine_No Date  Process  Bolt_No1   B1Value1  B1Value2  B1Value3  
Engine_No Date  Process  Bolt_No2   B2Value1  B2Value2  B2Value3        
Engine_No Date  Process  Bolt_No3   B3Value1  B3Value2  B3Value3  
Engine_No Date  Process  Bolt_No4   B4Value1  B4Value2  B4Value3
```

Can someone suggest a query that achieves this?

Comment: the sql table structure is not clear at all please review your question and format it (I tried but it still didn't make sense) in the toolbar {} is used to create fixed layout rows.

Comment: What sort of table is this?  One way would be to use `UNION` along with several different queries, but I wouldn't attempt this.

Comment: also looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742988/sql-server-row-to-columns

Answer (score 1):

You could do a select like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT
            Engine_No,
            Date,
            Process,
            Bolt_No1,
            B1Value1,
            B1Value2,
            B1Value3
        FROM
            Engines
    ) UNION (
        SELECT
            Engine_No,
            Date,
            Process,
            Bolt_No2,
            B2Value1,
            B2Value2,
            B2Value3
        FROM
            Engines
    ) UNION (
        SELECT
            Engine_No,
            Date,
            Process,
            Bolt_No3,
            B3Value1,
            B3Value2,
            B3Value3
        FROM
            Engines
    ) UNION (
        SELECT
            Engine_No,
            Date,
            Process,
            Bolt_No4,
            B4Value1,
            B4Value2,
            B4Value3
        FROM
            Engines
    )
) AS tmp
ORDER BY Engine_No
```

The only problem is that since each column can only have one name you won't know which rows have which columns.

What you would normally do in a situation like this is select what you need and then format it to how you want it to look in whatever language you display it in.